# App Development using AMD | Visual Studio Code / Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, hyper-v, amd-processor, haxm

Important: I have AMD Cpu and Windows 10 Home.
I want to start developing an app with flutter. I want to use Visual Studio Code or Android Studio as IDE.

But when I create a new virtual device and try to run it. Android Studio says:

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
> HAXM is not installed. Install Intel HAXM for better emulation performance.

But if I continue with the install, it says

[image: error1]

or

[image: error2]

The log file suggested in error2 says

[image: see here on screenshot]

I also tried with Hyper-V but this doesn't work because I don't have have the Hyper-V folder installed.
I guess that's because i am using Windows 10 Home (the free one) and not Pro.

I also tried to activate SVM in die UEFI, it was already activated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question by replacing screenshots with actual text. Not only do links die, but it poses problems for the visually impaired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Because i am using *AMD* cpu *and* *don´t own Windows 10 pro* license.
There was no other way than to buy an intel processor or to buy windows 10 pro.
That's why i decided to **upgrade windows**, now it is working with Hyper-V...